Understanding Uniform Convergence of a Sequence of Functions
I am currently self-studying and came across the following theorem:
Suppose that a sequence of functions $\phi_n$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[a,b]$. Now suppose we have a sequence of functions $f_n$ and a function $f$ on $[a,b]$ such that $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \phi_n(x)$$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. It is stated that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$.
However, I'm having difficulty understanding why this is obvious. Could someone please explain this to me? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Uniformly) $f_n→f$
iff $f_n−f→0$; and if $|g_n|≤ϕ_n$
and $ϕ_n→0$
then $g_n→0$.

$\phi_n$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[a, b]$ means for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$n \geq N \implies \lvert \phi_n(x) \rvert < \epsilon$$
for all $x \in [a, b]$. Observe
$$\lvert f_n(x) - f(x) \rvert \leq \phi_n(x) \implies \lvert f_n(x) - f(x) \rvert \leq \lvert \phi_n(x) \rvert$$
Therefore
$$n \geq N \implies \lvert f_n(x) - f(x) \rvert < \epsilon$$
which is the definition of uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$.

For any function $g:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$, define $$\|g\|:=\sup\{|g(x)|:x\in[a,b]\}\in[0,\infty].$$
By hypothesis, $\|f_n-f\|\le
\|\phi_n\|$ and $\|\phi_n\|$ converges to $0$, hence so does $\|f_n-f\|$.
